# My local branch was on master and I pushed to my remote repo that was on main but now I'm getting a 'non-fast-forward' error

Tags: git

It prompted me to run `git push origin HEAD` then I ran into this error:

```
! [rejected]        HEAD -> main (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Reidwilliamson13/tours-app.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: It actually tells you right in the error message what to do. Pull, then push.

Comment: I pulled and pushed and gave me the same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+hint%3A+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind

Answer (score -1):

git bash:

git pull --rebase origin HEAD

git push origin HEAD

Comment: Code-only answers are rarely useful. How about providing some explanation?